Wrong Rotantion with particles emitter along spline
I am having trouble with the particle emitter in Blender. When I try to emit some boxes along a spiral, the boxes are strangely distorted. I would like to know how I can make the boxes respect the orientation according to the image shown with the red lines?
 

This isn’t distortion of the particles, this is the curve twisting. I remember there’s a setting you can turn on in the spline to make it always point upward, but I don’t remember where it is.

@TheLabCat: do you think to the Object Data Properties > Shape > Twist Method panel, set to "Z-Up" ?
